# Github API v3: Update file not working (404)

Tags: javascript, jquery, github-api

I'm trying to update a file using the Github v3 api. Most of the documentation I could find was based on the older API. I want to utilize: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file

I first grab the file using:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/"+owner+"/"+repo+"/contents/"+path,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "user" + btoa(owner+":"+passwrd));
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonFile = data.content;
            sha = data.sha;
            var decodedJson = atob(jsonFile);
            var parsedDecodedJson = JSON.parse(decodedJson);
            parseData(parsedDecodedJson);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert.addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('hidden').html('Something went wrong:'+error.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Which works perfectly.

After editing the file, I try to update the file. 
On my submit I post the following using jQuery:

```
    var postData = {
        "message": "Update",
        "content":  btoa(obj),
        "sha": sha,
        "branch":"gh-pages"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/"+owner+"/"+repo+"/contents/"+path,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "user" + btoa(owner+":"+passwrd));
        },
        type: 'PUT',
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success!!!", data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Cannot get data", error);
        }
    });
```

All the variables contain the expected values. Regardless, I keep getting a 404. 
I know the API more often than not returns a 404 instead of something like a 403 as stated here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication But it makes debuggin nearly impossible in my opinion. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to do it is to make the entire round trip. 
I used a [javascript Github API wrapper](https://github.com/github-tools/github)

Luckily I found [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/pushing-a-list-of-files-to-the-github-with-javascript-b724c8c09b66) in which the bulk of the work was already been done. Props to Illia Kolodiazhnyi.

In the end. I ended up with this:

- [Handler on top of github api plugin](https://github.com/jansmolders86/gh-cms/blob/master/assets/javascript/GithubApiPush.js)
- Usage:

  ```
              var api = new GithubAPI({ token: token});
                          api.setRepo(owner, repo);
                          api.setBranch(branch).then(function () {
                              return api.pushFiles(
                                  'CMS Update',
                                  [
                                      {
                                          content: JsonData,
                                          path: path
                                      }
                                  ]
                              );
                          }).then(function () {
                              console.log('Files committed!');
                          });
  ```